# Getting Data from event in FULLCALENDAR with angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar, and I'm not sure how can I get the complete data of each event when I make a interaction with it, for example. I'm using the next calendar options:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    //plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      // right: 'prev,next,today,dayGridMonth,resourceTimeline,listMonth'
      right: 'prev,next,dayGridMonth'
    },
    dateClick: this.createTaskModal.bind(this),
    titleFormat: { month: 'long' }    ,
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    locale: esLocale,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    dayHeaders: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    editable: true,
    eventClick: this.updateModal.bind(this), //this.seeTask.bind(this),
    eventDrop: this.updateDates.bind(this),
    // weekends: false,
    events: this.events,
  }
```

so my problem is that the data that I get from eventClick or eventDrop looks like only the data that calendar use for paint all the tasks on calendar, but I need get the complete elements of the event, for example if my event have the next structure into the calendar:

```
title: "someTitle"
TaskId: "personalizedId"
end: "2020-21-04"
start: "2020-21-04"
Description: "MyOwnDescription"
```

I need that values that I'm putting into each event,so I'm trying to do it with the correct way?, how can I get all that information in drop and evenclick for use it into my functions?

Comment: If taskID and Description are missing from the information you get from eventClick, that's because they are non-standard properties and therefore were places in the "extendedProps" property of the event. This is documented - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing . So if you had an event object called `event` then `event.extendedProps.Description` would return the description. Does that help you? It was actually a tiny bit unclear from the question exactly what the issue was.

Comment: @ADyson that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

In fullCalendar your custom event data is in the "extendedProps" property

```
updateDates(info) {
     let yourData = info.event.extendedProps;
     // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with Angular, it's how fullCalendar works internally. I've edited your answer to be more accurate.

Comment: @ADyson I checked this and you are correct, in the past I used old version with jquery and recently I use it again with new version on angular and it changed on the version and not on the framework.